# Getting the width and height of an dynamic image in Vue Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have three images coming from an API response

```
<a v-for="partner_logo in page_content.partner_logo" :key="partner_logo" href="#" aria-label="partners">
    <img
     :ref="partner_logo"
     :data-src="partner_logo"
     alt="partnet logo"
     :width="// natural width here"
     :height="// natural height here"
     class="lazyload home-brand-logo hoverableArea"
    >
```

How can I get their original width and height to put them into attributes?

Comment: Using `:width="partner_logo.width"`? Or define "natural" here.

Comment: I don't think `"partner_logo.width"` will solve it .because `partner_logo` just an image source URL

Comment: Then, you will need to use a server or service in-between to get it's dimensions. There is no client side way (to my knowledge) being able to resolve an asset to have it's dimensions straight away.